# SystemJS + Karma + TypeScript - Not running test

Tags: javascript, typescript, phantomjs, karma-runner, systemjs

I am trying to run some unit tests for few days now without success. My application is written in typescript (the unit tests are written in typescript as well).
Here is my karma configuration file:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({

    basePath: "../../../../",

    frameworks: [
      "jasmine",
      "systemjs"
    ],

    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],

    singleRun: true,
    reporters: ['progress'],

    systemjs: {
      config: {
        paths: {
          systemjs: "src/main/webapp/static/js/engage/lib/bower/system.js/dist/system.src.js",
          typescript: "build/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js"
        },
        transpiler: "typescript"
      },

      // testFileSuffix: ".spec.ts"
    },

    files: [
      'src/main/webapp/static/js/engage/dist/vendor/vendor.min.js',
      'src/main/webapp/static/js/engage/lib/bower/system.js/dist/system-polyfills.src.js',
      'src/main/webapp/static/js/engage/lib/bower/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      {pattern: "src/main/webapp/static/js/engage/app/**/*.spec.ts", served: true, included: false}
    ]
  });
};
```

When I run `karma start` I get the following error:

```
05 09 2016 21:39:45.543:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.2.0 server started at http://localhost:9876/
05 09 2016 21:39:45.546:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser PhantomJS with unlimited concurrency
05 09 2016 21:39:45.558:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
05 09 2016 21:39:47.631:INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket /#c-ZoxCczyYymPDAtAAAA with id 8911412
05 09 2016 21:39:47.650:WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/src/main/webapp/static/js/engage/lib/bower/system.js/dist/system-polyfills.js
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
  You need to include some adapter that implements __karma__.start method!
```

If I change the browser property to Chrome, I get the following error:

```
Chrome 52.0.2743 (Mac OS X 10.11.6) ERROR
  Error: ReferenceError: jasmineRequire is not defined
            at eval (build/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js:14:32)
            at eval (build/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js:41:2)
        Evaluating build/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js
        Error loading build/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js
```

Here is my package.json relevant dependencies:

```
"phantomjs": "^1.9.11",
"karma-systemjs": "^0.14.0",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.1.5",
"jasmine-core": "^2.5.0"
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: FWIW if you are willing to consider using karma-jspm instead of karma-systemjs here is the question with a link to a repo with now hopefully working example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39028639/karma-jspm-typescript-not-found-ts-js

Comment: @artem, I couldn't find the link to the repo

Comment: it's https://github.com/Larchy/karma-jspm-typescript-coverage/tree/master

Comment: @artem, did you use it? did you manage to make it work for you?

Comment: nope, it's not mine

Comment: Have some suggestions -  1) Install Karma-PhantomJS-launcher 2)Upgrade to latest  versions of your dependencies (i.e. remove items from package.json and install latest for them.. 3)Look at this link - https://github.com/rolaveric/karma-systemjs/issues/78 4)Look at - https://github.com/taras42/karma-jasmine-html-reporter/issues/4

Answer (score 3):

1. I would try to include systemjs as first framework as it is written in documentation
2. Compile your typescript before loading it with systemjs and don't use systemjs typescript compile. That will decrease complexity of your karma tests which makes them more solid
3. Try changing included to true for your spec files, that helped me with some issues. But I'm not sure about that
4. leave your basePath at ./ as this als just makes trouble
5. Check the path to your system.js as it throws a 404 error

My configuration for system.js looks like this

```js
systemjs: {
    configFile: 'dev/systemjs.config.js',
    config: {
        map: {
            'systemjs':          'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js',
            'system-polyfills':  'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
            'es6-module-loader': 'node_modules/es6-module-loader/dist/es6-module-loader.js'
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe also some of the configuration snippets from this questions might help:
[Angular 2 + Karma + karma-jspm + karma-coverage + typescript report phantomJS failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38404476/angular-2-karma-karma-jspm-karma-coverage-typescript-report-phantomjs-fa/38979652#38979652)

Comment: Can you please show your karma config file as well?

Comment: It's in my answer to the other thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38979652/1512530

Comment: Can you please specify which nmp modules you are using? I don't need to have a coverage module, so what is irrelevant?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the plugins option to the karma config

```
plugins: [
  'karma-jasmine',
  'karma-chrome-launcher'
],
```

Use the last node.js 6.5 and update your dependencies to the latest version